# Centring a modal WPF window, in a full-screen app

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to create a modal confirmation dialog that always appears in the centre of the screen.

I've tried to use:

```
ConfirmCreate confirmCreate = new ConfirmCreate(); // ConfirmCreate extends Window.
bool? dialogResult = confirmCreate.ShowDialog();
confirmCreate.Owner = this;
confirmCreate.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

... and...

```
ConfirmCreate confirmCreate = new ConfirmCreate();
bool? dialogResult = confirmCreate.ShowDialog();
confirmCreate.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

... and even ...

```
ConfirmCreate confirmCreate = new ConfirmCreate(); // ConfirmCreate is a subclass of Window.
bool? dialogResult = confirmCreate.ShowDialog();
confirmCreate.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
confirmCreate.Left = Width/2 - confirmCreate.Width/2;
confirmCreate.Top = Height/2 - confirmCreate.Height/2;
```

To no avail, can someone explain why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try all your options with `confirmCreate.ShowDialog();` at the end. In other words, set the settings for `WindowStartupLocation`  and then call `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Yeah, spotted it as soon as I'd posted the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking at the code, I realised I was being a bit stupid.

If I set the properties before using the `ShowDialog()` method, the `CentreScreen` and `CentreOwner` properties do their job properly.

```
ConfirmCreate confirmCreate = new ConfirmCreate(); // ConfirmCreate extends Window.
confirmCreate.Owner = this;
confirmCreate.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
bool? dialogResult = confirmCreate.ShowDialog();
```

and ...

```
ConfirmCreate confirmCreate = new ConfirmCreate();
confirmCreate.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
bool? dialogResult = confirmCreate.ShowDialog();
```